# How to composite the view hierarchy to enhance animation performance?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, ipad, core-animation

I have several views with a lot of subviews, and during animation the performance is very poor.

One way that could help is to flatten the hierarchy by rendering it to a context. For this to work, each of the views which I want to be able to flatten must be constructed in such a way that all of their subviews are added to a container rather than directly to the view. Also, I must implement -drawRect: which performs the flattening of the hierarchy:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.containerLayer renderInContext:context];
}
```

The trick is that this container layer is not added as a sublayer of `self.layer`. For Core Animation it then looks like the hierarchy is flat.

But before trying something like this, is there a better way of doing it?

What concerns me is that I have to create an extra container layer which holds my view hierarchy for the view I want to flatten on demand. -drawRect: gets called only when I call -setNeedsDisplay so this seems fine.

Is there a way to flatten a view's subviews without the need for such a container?

The problem is that many of my subviews get added by calling -addSubview:, so there is no single layer I could flatten other than `self.layer` itself, if I wouldn't have a container instead.

What if I did this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.layer renderInContext:context];
}
```

This would not make much sense would it? I mean the entire hierarchy of subviews would be attached to this layer, but this layer is tied into the view, so rendering it into context is superflous as the view hierarchy will not be flat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look at `[CALayer shouldRasterize]`. It may handle much of what you're trying to do.

Second, having "many" subviews is often a bad idea. Views are heavyweight objects. Unless you need event (touch) handling on them all, you should really consider changing your views to layers. In some cases it can be worth it even if you have to do your own layer hit testing (i.e. let the view figure out which layer was touched).

Finally, calling `renderInContext:` in `drawRect:` is unlikely to give any benefit at all. Calling `renderInContext:` only really gives a benefit if you can call it either (a) on a background thread or (b) less often than `drawRect:`. Otherwise you're just doing all the same work.

Comment: -shouldRasterize doesn't flatten the hierarchy as I thought it would. When you try it in simulator, you'll see that there is still a lot of layer blending caused by all the sublayers, so shouldRasterize is not a performance boost.